# Is there a way to initiate a screen capture with Tkinter, or Pillow?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have an error logger that stores errors. I wanted to be able to also store screen shots. I tried using Pillow to do this and I was able to get it to grab, and save screen captures using code below.

```
import csv
import datetime
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
import configparser
from PIL import ImageGrab

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("C:/Users/Public/Documents/Intel/Strata/CfgFiles/Stationdata.ini")  #Locationdata for PD dataframe.

for key, value in config["StationData"].items():
    print(value)

snip_count = 0    
    
config.read("C:/Users/Public/Documents/Intel/Strata/CfgFiles/Appinfo.ini")

for key, version in config["About"].items():
    print(version)

def log_error(category, error):
    with open("//datagrovera.ra.intel.com/DeviceLabUser/Shared/Device lab Error Logger/error_log.txt", 'a', newline='')as error_log:
        writer = csv.writer(error_log, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow([datetime.datetime.now(), error, category, value, version])
        

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('300x515')
    root.title(value)
    category_var = tk.StringVar(root)
    category_var.set('Strata')
    category_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(root, category_var, 'Strata', 'Prober', 'General')
    category_dropdown.pack(pady=10)

    error_label = tk.Label(root, text='Error:')
    error_label.pack()
    v=tk.Scrollbar(root, orient='vertical')
    v.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
    error_entry = tk.Text(root, yscrollcommand=v.set)
    error_entry.pack(expand = True, fill = tk.BOTH )

    def log_error_callback():
        category = category_var.get()
        error = error_entry.get('1.0','end')
        if not error:
            messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Please enter an error message')
            return
        log_error(category, error)
        messagebox.showinfo('Success', f'Error logged for {category} category')

    def delete():
        error_entry.delete("1.0","end")

    log_button = tk.Button(root, text='Log Error', command=lambda:[log_error_callback(), delete()])
    log_button.pack()

    # Define a function to capture the screen snip
    def capture_snip():
    # Use the global variable
        global snip_count
    # Get the coordinates of the selected region
        x1 = root.winfo_rootx() + canvas.winfo_x()
        y1 = root.winfo_rooty() + canvas.winfo_y()
        x2 = x1 + canvas.winfo_width()
        y2 = y1 + canvas.winfo_height()
    # Grab the image of the region and save it to a folder with a unique name
        image = ImageGrab.grab().crop((x1,y1,x2,y2))
        image.save(f"snip_{snip_count}.png")
    # Increment the snip count
        snip_count += 1

# Create a canvas to draw the region
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=200, bg='white')
    canvas.pack()

# Create a button to capture the screen snip
    button = tk.Button(root, text='Capture', command=capture_snip)
    button.pack()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I was hoping to be able to create a button that did the screen capture, Lets me draw a rectangular area for capture, grabs the screen capture, and saves it all in one. I am having trouble getting my program to initiate, and let me draw the area for the screen capture. Is there a way to get Tkinter, or Pillow, or another python module/library that can initiate the screen capture?

Comment: In what way does the posted code fail to meet your needs?

Comment: My code pulls or "grabs" an existing screen shot. So you have to open the screen snipping program or use the windows hot key to get a screen capture first. I would like the button to start the screen capture. That way the user doesn't have to go open a separate program or worry about getting a screen capture beforehand.

Comment: You have already created the `Capture` button to do what you want, so I wonder what do you want actually?

Comment: I guess I wasn't entirely clear. My code only pulls the screen shot that is already captured. The user would have to go open the windows snipping tool and selecting an area to screen capture or press the prnt screen button before pressing the capture button on my program currently. I want my capture button to be able to do this for the user, so that they can press the capture button, and draw out the area desired for screen capture.

Answer (score 0):

Neither tkinter nor PIL offer an out-of-the-box screen grabbing capture functionality.

However, there are other libs that do - it looks like [MSS](https://pypi.org/project/mss/) is a great call, as it uses its own ctypes bindings for the appropriate API in each O.S.  and is very light-weight.

Just add `mss` as a dependency in your project, and follow the usage info as documented at https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/examples.html#opencv-numpy

Answer (score 0):

I once tried to implement some functions of "https://altools.co.kr/product/ALCAPTURE" in Python. I had a lot of help from this site to do so, so I'll show you some (crude) reference of the program I made then.

```
import tkinter as tk
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image, ImageTk, ImageDraw
import keyboard
import win32gui
from threading import Thread

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        screenshot_area_button=tk.Button(self, text="screenshot", command=screenshot_area)
        screenshot_area_button.pack()

def screenshot_area():
    class screenshot_area(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self):
            self.screen_width = GetSystemMetrics(78)
            self.screen_height = GetSystemMetrics(79)
            self.full_image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, self.screen_width, self.screen_height), all_screens=True)
            super().__init__()
            self.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "#000000")
            self.config(highlightbackground="#000000", cursor="crosshair")
            self.overrideredirect(True)
            self.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
            self.wm_attributes("-alpha", 0.4)
            self.geometry(f"{self.screen_width}x{self.screen_height}")
            self.rectx0 = 0
            self.recty0 = 0
            self.rectx1 = 0
            self.recty1 = 0
            self.rectid = None
            self.lineid = None
            self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=self.screen_width, height=self.screen_height)
            self.x, self.y = win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[2][0], win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[2][1]
            self.line_x = self.canvas.create_line(0, self.y, self.screen_width, self.y, fill="red", width=1)
            self.line_y = self.canvas.create_line(self.x, 0, self.x, self.screen_height, fill="red", width=1)
            self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.startRect)
            self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.stopRect)
            self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.movingRect)
            self.top = tk.Toplevel(self)
            self.top.overrideredirect(True)
            self.top.configure(bd=0, bg="#000000", highlightbackground="#000000")
            self.top_frame = tk.Frame(self.top, bd=1)
            self.top_frame.pack(fill="both")
            self.canvas_zoom = tk.Canvas(self.top_frame, width=151, height=151, bg="#000000")
            self.image_obj = self.canvas_zoom.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=None)
            self.textobj = self.canvas_zoom.create_text(30, 135, text=None, fill="red",
                                                        font=("Consolas", 11, "bold"))
            self.canvas_zoom.create_line(0, 76, 151, 76, fill="red", width=2)
            self.canvas_zoom.create_line(76, 0, 76, 151, fill="red", width=2)
            self.canvas_zoom.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
            self.poly_points = []
            self.t1 = Thread(target=self.reading_glasses)
            self.t1.start()
            self.t2 = Thread(target=self.image_update)
            self.t2.start()
            self.canvas.focus_set()
            keyboard.on_press(self.on_escape)

        def polygon_capture(self, *args):
            xy = args[0]
            x0, y0, x1, y1 = xy[0][0], xy[0][1], xy[0][0], xy[0][1]
            for i in xy:
                if x0 > i[0]: x0 = i[0]
                if y0 > i[1]: y0 = i[1]
                if x1 < i[0]: x1 = i[0]
                if y1 < i[1]: y1 = i[1]
            crop_area = (x0, y0, x1, y1)
            mask = Image.new("L", self.full_image.size)
            ImageDraw.Draw(mask).polygon(xy, fill=255, outline=None)
            black = Image.new("RGBA", self.full_image.size)
            result = Image.composite(self.full_image, black, mask)
            result = result.crop(crop_area)
            result = result.convert("RGBA")
            data = result.getdata()
            new_data = []
            for item in data:
                if item[0] == 255 and item[1] == 255 and item[2] == 255:
                    new_data.append((255, 255, 255, 255))
                else:
                    new_data.append(item)
            result.putdata(new_data)
            return result

        def rgb_to_hex(self, rgb):
            return "#%02x%02x%02x" % rgb

        def image_update(self):
            try:
                x, y = win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[2][0], win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[2][1]
                zoom_rect = x - 10, y - 10, x + 10, y + 10
                self.img = self.full_image.crop(zoom_rect).resize((151, 151), resample=Image.Resampling.NEAREST)
                self.imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.img, master=self)
                self.canvas_zoom.itemconfig(self.image_obj, image=self.imgtk)
                pixel_color = self.img.getpixel((75, 75))
                self.hex_color = self.rgb_to_hex(pixel_color)
                self.canvas_zoom.itemconfig(self.textobj, text=self.hex_color)
                self.image_up_id = self.top.after(20, self.image_update)
            except:
                pass

        def reading_glasses(self, event=None):
            try:
                self.top.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
                x, y = win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[2][0], win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[2][1]
                self.canvas.coords(self.line_x, 0, y, self.screen_width, y)
                self.canvas.coords(self.line_y, x, 0, x, self.screen_height)
                top_posx = x - 165
                top_posy = y + 15
                if top_posx < 0:
                    top_posx = x + 15
                if top_posy + 190 > self.screen_height:
                    top_posy = y - 190
                self.top.geometry(f"150x150+{top_posx}+{top_posy}")
                self.reading_id = self.top.after(1, self.reading_glasses)
            except:
                pass

        def startRect(self, event):
            self.rectx0 = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
            self.recty0 = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
            self.rectid = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.rectx0, self.recty0, self.rectx0, self.recty0,
                                                       outline="red", width=1, fill="#000000")
            self.lineid = self.canvas.create_line(self.rectx0, self.recty0, self.rectx0, self.recty0, width=1,
                                                  fill="red", joinstyle="bevel")
            if len(self.poly_points) > 2 and self.poly_points[0][0] == self.poly_points[-1][0] and \
                    self.poly_points[0][1] == self.poly_points[-1][1]:
                self.on_escape()
                img = self.polygon_capture(self.poly_points)
                img.save("screenshot.png", "PNG")
            self.poly_points.append((self.rectx0, self.recty0))

        def movingRect(self, event):
            self.rectx1 = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
            self.recty1 = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
            self.canvas.coords(self.rectid, self.rectx0, self.recty0, self.rectx1, self.recty1)

        def on_escape(self, event=None):
            try:
                self.top.after_cancel(self.image_up_id)
                self.top.after_cancel(self.reading_id)
                self.destroy()
                app.deiconify()

            except:
                pass

        def stopRect(self, event):
            try:
                self.rectx1 = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
                self.recty1 = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
                if ((self.rectx1 - self.rectx0) ** 2 + (self.recty1 - self.recty0) ** 2) ** (1 / 2) > 15:
                    self.canvas.coords(self.rectid, self.rectx0, self.recty0, self.rectx1, self.recty1)
                    self.on_escape()
                    try:
                        if self.rectx0 > self.rectx1:
                            self.rectx0, self.rectx1 = self.rectx1, self.rectx0
                        if self.recty0 > self.recty1:
                            self.recty0, self.recty1 = self.recty1, self.recty0
                        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(self.rectx0, self.recty0, self.rectx1, self.recty1),
                                             all_screens=True)
                        img.save("screenshot.png", "PNG")
                    except:
                        return
                else:
                    self.canvas.bind("<Motion>", self.line_move)
            except:
                return

        def line_move(self, event):
            if len(self.poly_points) > 1:
                if ((self.poly_points[0][0] - self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)) ** 2 + (
                        self.poly_points[0][1] - self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)) ** 2) ** (1 / 2) > 35:
                    self.rectx1 = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
                    self.recty1 = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
                    self.canvas.coords(self.lineid, self.rectx0, self.recty0, self.rectx1, self.recty1)
                else:
                    self.rectx1 = self.poly_points[0][0]
                    self.recty1 = self.poly_points[0][1]
                    self.canvas.coords(self.lineid, self.rectx0, self.recty0, self.poly_points[0][0],
                                       self.poly_points[0][1])
                    self.poly_points.append((self.poly_points[0][0], self.poly_points[0][1]))
            else:
                self.rectx1 = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
                self.recty1 = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
                self.canvas.coords(self.lineid, self.rectx0, self.recty0, self.rectx1, self.recty1)

    app.withdraw()
    capture = screenshot_area()
    capture.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=App()
    app.mainloop()
```

I hope this code will be helpful for your program.